# How to Save Multiple Tags to Database [Asp Mvc]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to save multiple tags to my database.

Here are my classes:

```
public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    // ...

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlSlug { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view (Create post View):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offet-3" })
    <div id="tags">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tags, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Book model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        Collection<Tag> postTags = new Collection<Tag>();
        var s = model.Tags.ToString();
        string[] newTags = s.Split(',');

        foreach (var val in newTags)
        {
            Tag iTag = new Tag
            {
                Name = val
            };
            db.Tags.Add(iTag);
            postTags.Add(iTag);
        }

        model.Tags = postTags;
        db.Books.Add(model);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

When I added a new post and checked the database, the BookTagMap table is working well, but the tags table saves the Tag Name like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartBookLibrary.Models.Tag]
```

Why is the Tag Name being saved as this particular string?

Data from the database:

[Tags - Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOA82.png)
[TagBooks - Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqVAA.png)

**Updated :**

When I used the Html Field , and get the id in controller it's worked , so the problem in html helper right now , how we can solve it ?

```
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id="tagg" name="tagg"/>
```

Controller :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Book model,string tagg)
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Shyju also mine , but I don't know , why it's saving this in db : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartBookLibrary.Models.Tag]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it totally saved the correct string values to the db column. Clean your solution and rebuild and see

Comment: Did you also copied the view code ? @Shyju

Comment: no! hardcoded `var s ="A,B";`. I think you should do this  `var s=model.Tags` and it should work.

Comment: Amasa's answer seems to explain your problem. Try that.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GAzPUgj.png    http://i.imgur.com/n5vVsKx.png   ||| when I did like that , it's work , but I don't like to use the html input , and want to use the html helper , so can you help with that ? @Shyju

Comment: You cannot bind a complex object to a textbox - your using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags)` and `Tags is a complex object

Comment: so how I can solve this Mr @StephenMuecke

Comment: Its a bit unclear from the code you have shown, but surely you want to create multiple tags and save all the properties i.e `UrlSlug` and `Description` as well as the `Name`? - in which case you need an entirely different approach

Comment: Ok thanks , i'll see what I can find out , also if you get a solution for that let me know please , and thanks for you help Sir @StephenMuecke

Comment: Start by looking at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for dynamically adding new items to a collection

Comment: Use '@html.listbox("tags")' for multiple tags ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartBookLibrary.Models.Tag] is the object name. Don't use toString() function.

```
var s = model.Tags;
```

Updated Answer:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }
    public virtual string TagsListing { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TagsListing, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offet-3" })
        <div id="tags">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagsListing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Collection<Tag> postTags = new Collection<Tag>();
            var s = book.TagsListing.ToString();
            string[] newTags = s.Split(',');

            foreach (var val in newTags)
            {
                Tag iTag = new Tag
                {
                    Name = val
                };
                db.Tags.Add(iTag);
                postTags.Add(iTag);
            }

            book.Tags = postTags;
            db.Books.Add(book);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GAzPUgj.png    http://i.imgur.com/n5vVsKx.png   ||| when I did like that , it's work , but I don't like to use the html input , and want to use the html helper , so can you help with that ? @jitendra-singh

Comment: @FirasMaswadeh  Problem here is with the design that you are following.
As per Model, you are accepting list of tags but view is generated to accept comma separate tags in string.

Displaying dynamic tags is fine in view but to add any number of tags you need to rethink about the view that you are generating.

Comment: There is another concept of ModelView. You can create another Model based on view which will accept tags as string (Or you can add virtual property in the same model to accept the same). And then you can achieve the functionality.

PFA the updated answer.

Comment: It's Done , 100% Works well , Can you please explain to me more about your answer , just to upgrade my skills , and thank you very much @Jitendra-Singh

Comment: Sure. So most of the time, our View need to display and accept inputs from users which are different than our generic models which represent database entities. In those cases, we can use ModelView concept to sync with our view. Here is an example that can help you more about it in detail - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: Thanks , If I want to retrieve them and display them in a post , what is you interest me to do , because I want to show for each post the tags related to it

Comment: You already have joining in your tables. You can simply fetch per post tags and can display.

Comment: Let me know if you facing any issue in it. I would love to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
var s = model.Tags.ToString();
```

you turn your list, `model.Tags`, into a string by calling `ToString` on a list (only to turn it back into a list on the next line, btw). Take a look at what string you get when you call `ToString` on a list: https://dotnetfiddle.net/c1SHvP

There's no reason to turn `model.Tags` into a string and then turn it back into a list. Just iterate over the original `model.Tags` in your `foreach`. Like this:

```
foreach (var tag in model.Tags)
{
    Tag iTag = new Tag
    {
        Name = tag.Name
    };
    db.Tags.Add(iTag);
    postTags.Add(iTag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Actually When I changed the View code to <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id="tagg" name="tagg"/> , and then received it in controller the problem is solved ! , so the problem was in view code , what do you think I should do to use the same view code and get it work ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GAzPUgj.png    http://i.imgur.com/n5vVsKx.png   ||| when I did like that , it's work , but I don't like to use the html input , and want to use the html helper , so can you help with that ? @Amasa

Comment: There was no need to change your view code. Keep your view code exactly like you had it in your question, and just change the `foreach` to iterate over `model.Tags`, like in my answer.

Comment: I got this error , when I did as you explained in your comment : http://i.imgur.com/3yiX7SC.png

Comment: In the image you linked in your first comment, your `foreach` is iterating over `newTags`, not, as my answer suggests, over `model.Tags`. Also, you added a parameter to your Controller method, `string tagg`, and added a matching input to the view. Those were unnecessary and caused the error you linked to an image of in your second comment. Change the view code back to how you had it in your question.

Comment: Hello, I did again as you said in last comment , get every thing back as was , and then filled the post info , clicked add , the page refresh again (error) , and this is my controller code (as you said to do ) : http://i.imgur.com/OYIlbtZ.png

Comment: No error ! , Just when I click add , it reload the same page again !

Comment: I assume that's because your controller is redirecting to the "Index" action at the end. I assumed this was what you wanted to do. If you don't want to redirect to the "Index" action or view after creating the book, change it to redirect somewhere else.

Comment: I changed the redirect from index to view , and I got this error http://i.imgur.com/ShVwHnx.png

Comment: Because this is a POST action, you should leave the `RedirectToAction` and change where you want to redirect to, if you want to redirect somewhere else.

What was the problem with the same page reloading again after creating the book?

Comment: Sir , it's very clear , when I using the html input it works well , when I use the mvc html and click on add post it's just refresh the same page again . and nothing happened . because when it's check in controller if (ModelState.IsValid) => no then it refresh the page cause I have those :ViewBag.User_ID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email");
            ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Category_id", "Category_name");

Comment: If your view is passing a list of tags into the `model.Tags` property in your controller, then the `foreach` I gave you should fix your problem of writing `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[SmartBookLibrary.Models.Tag]` to the database. If the `model.Tags` property is *not* being set to a list of tags, then I would do research on Razor HtmlHelpers and figure out how you can get a list of tags to be passed in from your view.

Comment: Ok thanks , and i'm waiting your response to me asap , because as you seen , when I use the html helper and assign @model.tags nothing is change , but when I used html with id and got it in controller , it's worked well , but you know , I should use the html helper , so i'm waiting you and thanks a lot for your time I appreciate that ...

Comment: If you're having a separate problem with your HtmlHelper, I would submit a new question. StackOverflow is a good place for questions and answers, and if it's a separate issue there should be a different question. This answer should fix your problem of writing System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartBookLibrary.Models.Tag] to the database. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it's solved , Actually the solution was very simple and I should did that by my self , but sometimes we makes a mistakes :) , thanks a lot for help and your nice solutions also ...